# QEMU emulating a Raspberry Pi doesn't have Internet capability?

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, qemu, wireless-bridge

I'm attempting to emulate a Raspberry Pi with a QEMU ARM emulator on my macOS Catalina 10.15.1 machine. Mostly following [this guide](https://blog.agchapman.com/using-qemu-to-emulate-a-raspberry-pi/), I've been using the latest Raspbian Lite (4.19 Buster) with the buster kernel from [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel). To get virtual networking on my macOS host, I've installed [TunTap](http://tuntaposx.sourceforge.net/). This gave me a virtual network interface on /dev/tap0. I've been running the pi with this command:

```
sudo qemu-system-arm \
-kernel kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster \
-append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" \
-hda raspbian-buster-lite.qcow \
-cpu arm1176 -m 256 \
-M versatilepb -dtb versatile-pb.dtb \
-no-reboot -serial stdio \
-net nic -net user \
-net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no \
-netdev user,id=tap0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 \
-device e1000,mac=00:00:ab:c9:df:03
```

The above command successfully manages to boot the pi, but it oddly doesn't have any Internet capability. I added 8.8.8.8 as a nameserver in /etc/hosts. If I ping google.com, it appears to be able to resolve the hostname, but it hangs indefinitely, leaving me with this until I Ctrl+C out:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

I tried to ssh in from my host computer after starting the service (using `sudo service ssh start`), which gave this result:

```
$ ssh -v 10.0.2.15 -p 5555
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/redacted/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.2.15 [10.0.2.15] port 5555.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/redacted/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

After Googling the problem, I found threads [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151860/ssh-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/797191/qemu-packer-ssh-failed-connection-reset-by-peer), and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/virtual-raspbian-on-qemu-unable-to-connect-to-the-internet), but I've had no luck as my system configuration files on RPI have been essentially the default, and my macOS host has been difficult in creating bridges. I've been wrestling with the [QEMU Wiki](https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking) to gain some sense of it, but I haven't been able to move forward from this point. Do you guys possibly have an idea of how this could possibly be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The command that worked for me is the following (on a Debian 10):

```sh
sudo qemu-system-arm \
  -machine versatilepb \
  -cpu arm1176 \
  -m 256 \
  -dtb ~/qemu-rpi-kernel/versatile-pb-buster.dtb \
  -kernel ~/qemu-rpi-kernel/kernel-qemu-4.19.50-buster \
  -append 'root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw' \
  -no-reboot \
  -serial stdio \
  -net nic \
  -net user,hostfwd=tcp::5022-:22 \
  -net tap,ifname=vnet0,script=no,downscript=no \
  -drive format=raw,file=qemu.img
```

Preparation:

- The image I used was built from https://github.com/rpi-distro/pi-gen
- The kernel was taken from https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel